# Get variable from tkinter entry

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to get a character name with a entry box in tkinter.

```
def create2():
   global created
   label.config(text ='You need to have a name.')
   entry = tk.Entry(storywindow, text = 'Enter your name...')
   entry.place(relx = .01, rely = .89, relheight = .1, relwidth = .69)
   hero.name = entry.get
```

How do I bind the user input to the variable?
Thanks

Update with my working code:

```
def stats():
    label.config(text = hero.name + '\n'+ hero.mclass+'\nLevel:    ' + str(hero.level)  )
    label.config(text = 'Hitpoints: '+ str(hero.hp) +'/'+str(hero.max_hp))

def create2():
    label.config(text ='You need to have a name.')
    txt = tk.Entry(storywindow)
    txt.place(relx = .01, rely = .89, relheight = .1, relwidth = .69)

def getname():
     name = txt.get()
     hero.name = name
     txt.destroy()
     submit.destroy()
     stats()

submit = tk.Button(storywindow, text= 'Submit', command = getname)
submit.place(relx = .7, rely = .89, relheight = .1, relwidth = .29)

def create():
    label.config(text ='Please choose a main class.')
    war = tk.Button(storywindow, text = 'Warrior', command = lambda:[warrior(),war.destroy(),mag.destroy(),rog.destroy(),pri.destroy()])
    war.place(relx = .01, rely = .94, relheight = .05, relwidth = .24)
    mag = tk.Button(storywindow, text = 'Mage', command =  lambda:[mage(),war.destroy(),mag.destroy(),rog.destroy(),pri.destroy()])
    mag.place(relx = .26, rely = .94, relheight = .05, relwidth = .24)
    rog = tk.Button(storywindow, text = 'Rogue', command =  lambda:[rogue(),war.destroy(),mag.destroy(),rog.destroy(),pri.destroy()])
    rog.place(relx = .51, rely = .94, relheight = .05, relwidth = .24)
    pri = tk.Button(storywindow, text = 'Priest', command =  lambda:[priest(),war.destroy(),mag.destroy(),rog.destroy(),pri.destroy()])
    pri.place(relx = .76, rely = .94, relheight = .05, relwidth = .23)
```

Comment: At no point in the code you posted does any "user input" exist!  You have merely created the Entry, the user has had no time to do anything with it yet.  You have to do the `.get()` (note the parentheses), along with anything that depends on that value, *after* the user has indicated that they've finished entering the text - typically this will be in a function passed as the `command=` option of a Button.

Comment: Can you show all your code?

Comment: `Entry` (in all GUIs)  doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for user's data and you have to use ie. `Button` to run code which get data from `Entry` after you put data in `Entry` and press `Button`.

Comment: I can add my code to something else, it's 500+ lines long. I actually got this working on my own with none of these answers... But thanks anyways.  It's still a work in progress as I'm self learning Python and still in early stages.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `callback`, the line `data = str(my_entry.get())` is what you are looking for. I made a little example for you : you can write text in the Entry, then press Button, and the text will appear in the bottom area.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback():
    data = str(my_entry.get())
    my_entry.delete("0", "end")
    print(data)
    my_text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    my_text.insert("insert", data)

root = tk.Tk()

my_entry = tk.Entry(master=root)
my_entry.pack()

my_button = tk.Button(master=root, command=callback, text="Print text")
my_button.pack()

my_text = tk.Text(root, width=10, height=5)
my_text.insert("insert", "Hello !")
my_text.see("end")
my_text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I actually got it working, I will update my code with my working code block